# A way how to center text in an image div

Tags: html, image, text, center

I'm searching a way how to center text in an image div
I wanna have the name(Ronaldo) in the center without affecting other texts. Is there anyone who could help me?
Live demo: `"https://jsfiddle.net/ntasa5bc/1/"`

Thanks!

Julan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "Ronaldo" is in an `<h2>` tag that is absolutely positioned, you need to give it a width and set the text-align to center.

```
#name {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 172px;
  width: 238px; // the same width as the gold badge image
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you O to the A !! It worked :D